# Best method to make file executable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I need to be able to execute a file via code, which works great, but to make sure it succeeds I first have to set the executable bit on the file.  I am currently running `chmod +x` via an NSTask, but this seems clumsy:

```
NSString *script = @"/path/to/script.sh";
// At this point, we have already checked if script exists and has a shebang
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager isExecutableFileAtPath:script]) {
    NSArray *chmodArguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"+x", script, nil];
    NSTask *chmod = [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/bin/chmod" arguments:chmodArguments];
    [chmod waitUntilExit];
}
```

Any suggestions? I have not had any luck finding code examples, and the only other option seems to be NSFileManager's `setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:` with the `NSFilePosixPermissions` attribute. I'll do the POSIX read and write logic if I need to, but wanted to see if there's a more elegant method out there.

Comment: Just a little note: since string literals are constant, there's no need to use `+[NSString stringWithString:]` in the first line.

Comment: Yeah, that's not in my actual code (included just to make it super clear what script represents), but I've modified it to be more sensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is inelegant about the `NSFileManager` method is having to build up a dictionary structure, which is horribly verbose. The POSIX approach would be:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

const char path[] = "hardcoded/path";

/* Get the current mode. */
struct stat buf;
int error = stat(path, &buf);
/* check and handle error */

/* Make the file user-executable. */
mode_t mode = buf.st_mode;
mode |= S_IXUSR;
error = chmod(path, mode);
/* check and handle error */
```

Comment: Agreed, it was the dictionary that left a bad taste in my mouth. I will give the POSIX method a try to improve the speed, and maybe switch to `setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:` if the C code grates on me too much. Thanks folks, and thanks for the example code Jeremy!

Answer (score 4):

Use `-setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:`. What’s not elegant about it?

Another possibility is to use [`chmod(2)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/chmod.2.html), a POSIX function.

The solution you’ve listed in your question is expensive — running a task is equivalent to creating a new process on the operating system, which is definitely more expensive than using `NSFileManager` or `chmod(2)`.

Comment: `-setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:` is definitely the correct way to handle this.